# Linux from scratch: 'tools/include' is not a directory when installing linux-5.5.3 API Headers

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, linux-from-scratch

I am working on linux from scratch and I am at section 5.6 linux-5.5.3 API Headers. I was able to extract the tar, cd into the new directory, and make. At this point I am inside the linux-5.5.3 directory. The command I am having trouble with is this:

```
cp -rv usr/include/* /tools/include
```

It just returns:

```
cp: target '/tools/include' is not a directory
```

What does work for me is changing the command to:

```
cp -rv usr/include/* ./tools/include
```

I did this because the only "tools" directory I know of is two levels up at the top. Here is an approximate tree:

```
mnt/lfs (mount point for the lfs partition)
|-sources
| |-*Many tar archives*
| |-linux-5.5.3
|   |-*Some Directories*
|   |-usr
|     |-include
|-tools
```

I followed along with the book 100% and compiled all the other packages as instructed.

**My question: How should I proceed? Should I just do what works with the upper-level "tools" directory or should I go back and troubleshoot? If I should troubleshoot, what specifically should I do?**

This is the chapter I am reading for reference: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/linux-headers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I followed along with the book 100%

No, you did not. The symlink from `/tools` to `$LFS/tools` is created in [chapter 4.2 *Creating the `$LFS/tools` Directory*](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/creatingtoolsdir.html):

> ```sh
> mkdir -v $LFS/tools
> ln -sv $LFS/tools /
> ```

You ask:

> what specifically should I do?

It is *imperative* that you follow the instructions *exactly*. It is even more important that for each and every command in the book, you *fully* understand the command, you fully understand what the command does, you fully understand *why* the command is there, and you fully understand why the command is *at that place*.

> How should I proceed? Should I just do what works with the upper-level "tools" directory […]?

This is a good example of the above: this can't work, and it is important to understand *why* it can't work.

Comment: Okay. I now understand the issue. Is it possible to add that symbolic link right now, or do I have to start from the top?